# Check Vector type

Tags: java, generics, vector

I want to know if Vector is holding `<String>` or `<Integer>`.

my function `public void printVector(Vector <?> v){`

I tried `if(v instanceof <String>)` but the compiler won't allow it.
whats the issue?

Comment: *FYI:* You really shouldn't be using `Vector`. Recommendation (since Java 1.2 in 1998) is to use `ArrayList`.

Comment: yeah, I know... the requirement is Vector though. @Andreas

Comment: A `Vector<?>` can hold many objects of *different* types, because the `?` *could* mean `Object`, so your vector can hold *both* `String` *and* `Integer` objects at the same time. Only way to know, is to check all elements in the vector.

Comment: But how could I know if the vector that sent to the function is specific holding Strings or Ints?

Comment: You don't because of _type erasure_. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You can't. [Type-erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/339699/5221149) prevents that.

Comment: **the more specific problem** I'm sending a different vector to a function which decides what to do with the vector, according to the vector type.
I'm simulating a company, I have a vector of Employees, Customers. So I need to know the difference so I could use it right.@MickMnemonic

Comment: Hey,
a way you could use is to get an iterator for the vector, checking if it hasNext then using the getClass method on next.
Note that this makes subclassing a problem (unless you have a few "superclasses" you want to test against)

Answer (score 0):

A code example that may be relevant:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Cool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Vector<Integer> v;
         v = new Vector<>(5);
         v.add(Integer.valueOf(5));
         test(v);
    }

    private static void test(Vector<?> v) {
        Iterator<?> iterator = v.iterator();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next().getClass());     
        }
    }
}
```

This will print out class java.lang.Integer.

Your "test" method will have to check the type against a set of superclasses you're interested in (Employee/Customer/etc).

Also, Using vectors is generally considered bad practice in java.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you cannot know, because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Basically, it means that you cannot get the generic type of the vector at runtime.

Now, in a real application, if you know that every objects are of the same type, you can get the first one and check its type with [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2).

**Note** : this is not a good practice. Avoid that if you can. And as said by the others, you should consider other collections than Vector.

**Note** : as a rule of thumb, using `instanceof` is a clue of design flaw. Also, this is a costly operation.

If there is no first element, then your array is empty so you can just drop it.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, Java's type erasure will make the compile-time generic type information unavailable run-time.

A common workaround for this is to pass the `Class` of the generic parameter as a method argument. This way you can then check whether the method was indeed passed a list of `Customer`s or `Employee`s:

```
 public void print(List<?> list, Class<?> clazz) {

    if (clazz == Employee.class) {
        // ...
    } else if (clazz == Customer.class) {
       // ...
    } else {
      // ...
    }        
}
```

You could then call the method as follows:

```
 Vector<Employee> legacy = new Vector<>();
 // do stuff       
 print(legacy, Employee.class);
```

Note that resorting to `instanceof` or `class` checks is usually a sign of bad object oriented design and in general, you can achieve a more elegant solution through polymorphism, i.e. overriding the `print()` method for different object types -- or having a single `print()` method that utilizes different `toString()` implementations of the domain objects.